# How do I hover over a drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css

I working on making a drop-down menu and it seems when I put the display to none it goes away completely. And when you click on it you can type in the box but I don't want that. I am trying to make so the drop-down list pops up when you hover over it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0C133C;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}

.subnav class{
  margin: 0;
position:relative;
}

 .subnav > div a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #0C133C;
     font-size: 18px;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 9px;
}
  
.logo {
margin-top: 1rem;
}

.subnav {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin-right: 1rem; 

}

.split {
  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -50;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #282C41;
color: white;
margin-top: .5rem;
 font-size: 15px;
}

 
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
margin-top: .5rem;
font-size: 18px;
}


.dropdown { 
position: relative;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 375px;
height: 35px;
}

.dropdown:: before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 15px;
width: 8px;
height: 8 px;
}

.dropdown input {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 80px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px;
padding: 8px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown .option {
position: absolute;
top: 52px;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
left: 83px;
display: none; 
}

.dropdown .option div {
padding: 12px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .option div:hover
{
background: #62baea;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
    

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        

<subnav class="subnav subnav-light bg-light">
<img src="universallogo.jpg" class="logo"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="subnav=brand" href="#">
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Bonds</a>
</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Report a Claim</a>
 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About Us</a>
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
</div>
</subnav>
 

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>GET YOUR LICENSE & PERMIT BONDS FAST & EASY</h1>
    <p>We provide our Customers with a fast, easy, and secure way to get bonded. Get your Free Quote in minutes.
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">

<div class="dropdown">
<input type="text" class="textBox"
placeholder="Select Your State">
<div class="dropdown-content">
<div class="option">
<div onclick="show('California')">California</div>
<div onclick="show('Illinois')">Illionis</div>
<div onclick="show('Michigan')">Michigan</div>
<div onclick="show('Ohio')">Ohio</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[![My droplist wont apear][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGmxt.png

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.dropdown:hover  .option {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this kind of worked, but the droplist won't come down when I hover only when I click on it. And the list won't go back up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container element to create the dropdown menu and add the dropdown links inside it.
Wrap a `<div>` element around the button and the  to position the dropdown menu correctly with CSS.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).